# Rails Error | Errno::ENOENT in Categories#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

When I navigate to my categories/new url I get the following error:

```
Errno::ENOENT in Categories#new
Showing c:/Users/Javi/desktop/rails_projects/testing_basics/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/Javi/AppData/Local/Temp/execjs20150429-4112-xc20tpjson
Rails.root: c:/Users/Javi/desktop/rails_projects/testing_basics
```

What does this mean? This a bit above my expertise..

This is my stack trace:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-04-29 16:43:08 -0700
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.h
tml.erb (42.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 382ms (Views: 266.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/categories/new" for ::1 at 2015-04-29 16:43:14 -0700
Processing by CategoriesController#new as HTML
  Rendered categories/new.html.erb within layouts/application (286.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1434ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/Javi/AppData/Local/Temp/execjs201504
29-6172-1x8co6xjson):
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>TestingBasics</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
    9: <body>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__246374537_52769568'


  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/template
s/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/template
s/rescues/_trace.html.erb (10.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/template
s/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/template
s/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (258.6ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html
.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.er
b within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_conso
le_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_
markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.e
rb within layouts/javascript (268.8ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb
within layouts/javascript (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.j
s.erb within layouts/javascript (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.e
rb (617.9ms)
```

Seems like it might be a gem problem? Or maybe I accidentally deleted something in a recent project that is messing with my rails installer or devkit and the likes?

Answer (score -1):

Rails requires a Javascript execution library. Install nodejs, or include the therubyracer gem in your gemfile.

Comment: I tried installing the ruby racer gem but it didin't work, I also have node installed as I have installed it a few months back, but all of a sudden this started happening this week.

Comment: Can you mention your sass-rails version?